# Scaling tiles for missing zoom levels in Leaflet?

Tags: raster, leaflet, zoom, tile-layer

I have two sets of tiles. One for zoom level **10** and one for zoom level **14**. However, I want to be able to see tiles on my map at zoom levels **9 through 15**. For the nonexistent sets of tiles I want to use the tiles from either level 10 or 14 and scale them accordingly. E. g. at the zoom level **9, 11 and 12** I want to have the tiles from the level **10** displayed, but **scaled** by factor **0.5, 2 and 4** respectively and at the zoom level **13 and 15** I want to have the tiles from the level **14** displayed and **scaled** by factor **0.5 and 2**. I can achieve this for the levels 9 and 15 using the "**maxNativeZoom**" and "**minNativeZoom**" options, but how to do this with the other zoom levels?

In Open Layers, which I am using now I can solve this by specifying the "**server resolutions**" and "**client resolutions**" options. Now I want to try Leaflet - mostly because of better handling of overlays. That means I want to find a solution that works with overlays, like markers.

I've been looking at the [setTransform](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#domutil-settransform) function, which probably scales the tiles in the case of max/minNativeZoom, but my knowledge of Javascript and HTML is limited and I couldn't figure out how to use it.

Here's my scratch:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Leaflet map</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />
        <script src="leaflet.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mapid" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div> 
        <script>
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([46.5, 8], 10);
L.tileLayer('tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{maxNativeZoom: 14, maxZoom: 15, minNativeZoom: 10, minZoom: 9}).addTo(mymap);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use [Leaflet.LimitZoom](https://github.com/Zverik/Leaflet.LimitZoom) plugin. It makes possible to specify native zoom levels and allowed zoom levels. Missing zooms are interpolated from existing native zooms.

Allowed zoom levels are declared with `zooms` option when creating map. Native zoom levels are declared with `nativeZooms` option when creating layer.

In your case it would look something like:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
  zooms: [9, 10, 11 ,12, 13, 14, 15],
  minZoom: 9,
  maxZoom: 15
}).setView([46.5, 8], 10);

L.tileLayer('tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
  nativeZooms: [10, 14]
}).addTo(mymap);
```

What's missing in plugin is some kind of control over interpolation: which native zoom level is used when during interpolation, but this could probably be easly overcome by modifying/extending plugin.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect on my map. May be that the last update was for Leaflet 1.0.2 and I am using 1.5.1?

Comment: It works for me with leatest Leaflet. Did you include both `Leaflet.LimitZoom.js` and `Leaflet.ContinuousZoom.js` libraries?

Comment: Yes. This is my code `<html>
 <head>
  <title>Leaflet map</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />
  <script src="leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="Leaflet.LimitZoom.js"></script>
  <script src="Leaflet.ContinuousZoom.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body>
  <div id="mapid" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div> 
  <script>
var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
 zooms: [9, 10, 11 ,12, 13, 14, 15],
 minZoom: 9,
 maxZoom: 15
}).setView([46.5, 8], 10);
L.tileLayer('tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
 nativeZooms: [10, 14]
}).addTo(mymap);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>`

Comment: Here is JSFiddle that works with latest Leaflet: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/ed4rfabx/2/. If you inspect in browser with network debugger, you'll see that only tiles from zoom 10 and 14 are fetched.

Comment: Well it turned out I downloaded the html page with the link to .js files, instead of the .js-es themselves. I always get confused with downloading of code from Github. However, now it works "like a charm". The only drawback is - as you mentioned - that it's deciding itself which levels to use where. But I can live with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I can achieve this for the levels 9 and 15 using the "maxNativeZoom" and "minNativeZoom" options, but how to do this with the other zoom levels?

Yuo can do that with `max`/`minNativeZoom` as well!

> E. g. at the zoom level 9, 11 and 12 I want to have the tiles from the level 10 displayed, but scaled by factor 0.5, 2 and 4 respectively [...]

So in that case, define a tilelayer with both `maxNativeZoom = 10` and `minNativeZoom = 10`, like:

```
L.tileLayer("tilesForZoom10/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
    maxNativeZoom: 10,
    minNativeZoom: 10,
    minZoom: 9,
    maxZoom: 12,
});
```

> [...] and at the zoom level 13 and 15 I want to have the tiles from the level 14

Same thing:

```
L.tileLayer("tilesForZoom14/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
    maxNativeZoom: 14,
    minNativeZoom: 14,
    minZoom: 13,
    maxZoom: 15,
});
```

This will give you two separate tilelayers, which you can manage as one by creating a `L.LayerGroup` (for use in a `L.Control.Layers` etc), e.g.:

```
var tiles10 = L.tileLayer("tilesForZoom10/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
    { maxNativeZoom: 10, minNativeZoom: 10, minZoom: 9, maxZoom: 12 });
var tiles14 = L.tileLayer("tilesForZoom10/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
    { maxNativeZoom: 14, minNativeZoom: 14, minZoom: 13, maxZoom: 15 });

var tiles = L.layerGroup([tiles10, tiles14]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried the approach you suggested, but it looks like the webpage always loads the tiles from both layers for any zoom level. For example when I zoom out to level 10, it still loads all the tiles from level 14. After the loading is finished, the 14-tiles are removed, however it is causing an unnecessary (and quite long) delay.
Also when I reload the page, it lands on zoom 12, even if I specify 14 in `L.map()`. To me it seems like the `minZoom` and `maxZoom` options are ignored.